# Node EADDRINUSE error - a real solution?

Tags: node.js, port, nodemon

I'm running node on ubuntu and I keep getting the "error opening port: 8080...", the EADDRINUSE error.

I understand basically what the problem is, but when I search for search for solutions, I basically get debates about the best way to kill the process. The other thing is people saying that you need to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> - that is not an issue because I always use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and I get this error even when nodemon restarts the server.

Is there a real solution to this? Having to kill the process each time is clumsy and ugly. Plus, I am having to do this 20 times an hour. To make matters worse, this sometimes kills my Postman when I kill the process.

So, is there a ***real*** solution. In order of preference:

1. Is there a way to keep this from happening in the first place? Why doesn't node or nodemon kill the process it was running?
2. It there are way to problematically (in my node server) telling it to kill the process before the server crashes/exits?
3. Is there a way to kill existing processes within my server, before it starts listening on the port? I don't like this solution, but it's better that having to pound the port with a hammer every time so I can get it to work.

EDIT:

This is the error:

```
error opening port: 8080
{ Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1476:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/ksjazzguitar/Programming/test/jwt5/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ksjazzguitar/Programming/test/jwt5/server/server.js:46:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 8080 }
```

Comment: Killing the process will depend on your environment, could you post a little more info on that. Also, when are you running into this issue? Something else is using the port, do you know what it is and can you prevent it from starting in the first place?

Comment: I am running the latest node and nodemon on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I know exactly what was using the port - the server I'm working on that I just killed or crashed. It just doesn't go away. I'm working right now - in the last 30 minutes, at least 40 time my app has exited/crashed and when I try to restart I get this error so I kill the port on the CL and restart Postman and star the cycle again.

Comment: Node 8.9.4 Nodemon 1.15.1 - the problem happens whether I use node or nodemon, whether I ctrl-c the server or it crashes or even if nodemon reboots it. This used to happen in my Windows environment too.

Comment: Something tells me it's a problem with your setup or something else. When a process dies it will release the port so starting up the process again after e.g. a crash (or simply restarting) should not be a problem. Could you tell us a little more about your setup? Maybe show us some code or how your package.json is setup to run nodemon.

Comment: It sounds like his process isn't actually dying. It goes defunct then tries to start listening again

Comment: What is causing your application to crash / stop functioning?

Comment: Just when I'm buidling a new express server - today I was working on the registration endpoint for an auth route. I don't understand how what I am doing could keep nodemon from doing what it is supposed to do. The only other thing is that I was running Postman. Could that be holding the port open somehow? I can't remember if this happens more often when I'm running Postman or not.

Comment: Sorry, Idk. According to nodemon it should kill your server and start it up again when it detects changes to files in your project, no Ctrl-C necessary either as long as you start your application using nodemon and not node

Comment: Any chance your application is starting up another process then starting the server in there? In that case when nodemon kills the application the other process could live on locking up the port

Comment: @Steve - If I understand you, I have made that mistake where I accidentally `app.listen` twice (usually a cut and paste error). This is not the case - as soon as I kill the process manually, it runs fine - until I kill it.

Answer (score 2):

In one of my Node servers, I added this:

```
const processExitHandler = async (error) => {
  await this.destroy();
  if(error) console.log(error);
  process.exit(error ? 1 : 0);
};

process.on('exit', processExitHandler);
process.on('SIGINT', processExitHandler); // Catches ctrl+c
process.on('SIGUSR1', processExitHandler); // SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 are for `kill pid` (ex: nodemon restart)
process.on('SIGUSR2', processExitHandler);
process.on('uncaughtException', processExitHandler);
```

`this.destroy` stops webservers and the database connection.

And here are my watch scripts for compiling/restarting on changes:

```
"watch:build": "babel src --out-dir lib --source-maps --watch",
"watch:run": "nodemon lib/index.js",
"watch": "npm run watch:build & (sleep 1 && npm run watch:run)",
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was looking for for a third option. Unfortunately, it's topped doing it so there is no way to test it right now. If it starts doing it, I'll throw this in there and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

To answer 3 and 2

3) You can kill the process with this

```
# where 8080 is your port
sudo kill <(sudo lsof | grep 'TCP \*:8080 (LISTEN)' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u)
```

2) Create a bash script with 3) in it then the command to start your app, something like

```
sudo kill <(sudo lsof | grep 'TCP \*:8080 (LISTEN)' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u)
npm start
```

Then use that script to start your application

Comment: Yes, I know how to kill the process. That wasn't the issue. Yes, if my car doesn't start, I know how to hit the fuel injector with a hammer.  I'm looking for a solution other than a hammer.

Comment: Do you know what exception is being thrown in your server, anyway to catch it?

Comment: Sorry, how would I capture that? This what I'm getting: (see orig post).

Answer (score 0):

I simply added the flag --delay 1500ms in my pkg.json and it worked.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./src/index.js --delay 2000ms"
},
```